# How do you convert many files from .xlsx to .xls?

Tags: file-format, conversion, xls

What is a way to convert a batch of .xlsx files to .xls format?   I would prefer it to be a command-line solution, but anything is better than opening each manually, and manually saving in the new format.

~~Edit~~

So is there a way to get around that error?

```
errored: Leaking python objects bridged to UNO for reason pyuno runtime is not initialized, 
(the pyuno.bootstrap needs to be called before using any uno classes) 
python: tpp.c:63: __pthread_tpp_change_priority: 
Assertion `new_prio == -1 || (new_prio >= __sched_fifo_min_prio && new_prio <= __sched_fifo_max_prio)' failed. 
Aborted
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use unoconv:

```
sudo apt-get install unoconv
ls *.xlsx | xargs unoconv -f xls
```

You may need to start "unoconv -l" on a differente terminal to provide the OO listener service.

Comment: errored: Leaking python objects bridged to UNO for reason pyuno runtime is not initialized, (the pyuno.bootstrap needs to be called before using any uno classes)
python: tpp.c:63: __pthread_tpp_change_priority: Assertion `new_prio == -1 || (new_prio >= __sched_fifo_min_prio && new_prio <= __sched_fifo_max_prio)' failed.
Aborted

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ssconvert](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-convert-xlsx-files-to-xls-or-csv.html):

```
ssconvert --export-type=Gnumeric_Excel:excel_dsf "/path/uno.xlsx" "/path/dos.xls"
```

Comment: That did some stuff, although the resulting file is in "Unsupported format" according to gnumeric.
Here's the error:  "(ssconvert:28773): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed"

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use [xlsx2csv](https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv). Put the files in a directory and then:

```
sudo easy_install xlsx2csv

xlsx2csv.py /path/to/input/dir
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/5256733/